# How to wrap a borrowed value in a newtype that is also a borrowed value?

Tags: reference, rust, borrowing, newtype

I am trying to use the [newtype pattern](https://github.com/rust-unofficial/patterns/blob/master/patterns/newtype.md) to wrap a pre-existing type. That inner type has a `modify` method which lets us work with a borrowed mutable value in a callback:

```
struct Val;

struct Inner(Val);

impl Inner {
    fn modify<F>(&self, f: F)
    where F: FnOnce(&mut Val) -> &mut Val { … }
}
```

Now I want to provide a very similar method on my newtype `Outer`, which however should not work on `Val`s but again a newtype wrapper `WrappedVal`:

```
struct Outer(Inner);
struct WrappedVal(Val);

impl Outer {
    fn modify<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut WrappedVal) -> &mut WrappedVal,
    {
        self.0.modify(|v| f(/* ??? */));
    }
}
```

This code is a reduced example from the original API. I don't know why the reference is returned from the closure, maybe to facilitate chaining, but it shouldn't be necessary. It takes `&self` because it uses internal mutability - it's a type representing a peripheral register on an embedded system

**How do I get a `&mut WrappedVal` from a `&mut Val`?**

I have tried various things, but all were busted by the borrow-checker. I cannot move the `Val` out of the mutable reference to construct a proper `WrappedVal`, and I couldn't get lifetimes to compile either when experimenting around with `struct WrappedVal(&'? mut Val)` (which I don't really want actually, since they are complicating a trait implementation).

I eventually got it to compile (see [Rust playground demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9cea24b6cd2da5e4439aba11ff5002fd)) using the absolute horror of

```
self.0.modify(|v| unsafe {
    (f((v as *mut Val as *mut WrappedVal).as_mut().unwrap()) as *mut WrappedVal as *mut Val)
        .as_mut()
        .unwrap()
});
```

but surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no safe way with your current definition, and your unsafe code is not guaranteed to be safe. There's no contract that the layout of a `WrappedVal` matches that of a `Val`, even though that's all it holds.

## Solution not using `unsafe`

Don't do it. Instead, wrap the reference:

```
struct WrappedVal<'a>(&'a mut Val);

impl Outer {
    fn modify<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce(WrappedVal) -> WrappedVal,
    {
        self.0.modify(|v| f(WrappedVal(v)).0)
    }
}
```

## Solution using `unsafe`

You can state that your type has the same *representation* as the type it wraps, making the pointers compatible via [`repr(transparent)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-transparent-representation):

```
#[repr(transparent)]
struct WrappedVal(given::Val);

impl Outer {
    fn modify<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut WrappedVal) -> &mut WrappedVal,
    {
        self.0.modify(|v| {
            // Insert documentation why **you** think this is safe
            // instead of copy-pasting from Stack Overflow
            let wv = unsafe { &mut *(v as *mut given::Val as *mut WrappedVal) };
            let wv = f(wv);
            unsafe { &mut *(wv as *mut WrappedVal as *mut given::Val) }
        })
    }
}
```

With `repr(transparent)` in place, the two pointers are interchangable. I ran [a quick test with Miri and your full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba52173d1b9ab1eecc0ee811f930d97f) and didn't receive any errors, but that's not a silver bullet that I didn't mess something else up.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `repr(transparent)`, I didn't know about that. How should I argue that the cast is safe - surely if the values have the same memory representation, I should be able to call methods from both types on the same memory location? Do I need to assess any other aspect?

Comment: I had attempted the safe solution where a `&mut Val` is wrapped, but as hinted at in the question [I couldn't get the lifetimes right](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6d97d932ee73c996ad2a28b605ebe92b). I don't want to litter my code (especially `Outer`) with lifetime parameters  that will only be needed locally in one method for `WrappedVal`, am I approaching this wrong? I'm already surprised that you could omit the lifetime argument in `FnOnce(WrappedVal) -> WrappedVal`.

Comment: @Bergi yes, using lifetimes like that in a trait is beyond what Rust can currently express; [generic associated types (GATs)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md) need to be implemented first. Traits are more complicated than plain functions due to their flexibility.

Comment: @Bergi My comment inside the code is meant to dissuade future people from just copy-pasting the code without reading the rest of the answer. My belief that the code is safe comes from the usage of `repr(transparent)`, so that's what I'd use in my comment, yeah.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [ref_cast](https://docs.rs/ref-cast/1.0.0/ref_cast/) library you can write:

```
#[derive(RefCast)]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct WrappedVal(Val);
```

Then you can convert using `WrappedVal::ref_cast_mut(v)`.