# How can I change the data pointer of dynamic dispatch / a trait object?

Tags: rust, dynamic-dispatch, trait-objects, shared-data

I have a `Vec<u8>` named `vec` and a variable named `x` of type `&dyn Trait`. I want the data pointer of `x` to point to a position in `vec`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let vec: Vec<u8> = vec![35, 1, 51, 10];

    let x: &dyn Debug;

    // create a &dyn Debug with its data pointer
    // pointing to vec[2] while the vtable points
    // to Point's implementation of Debug

    println!("{:?}", x); // expected output: "Point { x: 51, y: 10 }"
}
```

I'm trying to develop a virtual machine like the JVM. Every struct (`Point`, `Line`) that implements the desired trait (`Display` or `Debug`) will actually be an instruction (`Add`, `Mov`, ...) which will implement the trait `Instruction`, this trait contains the code of the instruction itself.

Here's another example that is closer to what I want to do:

```rust
use std::fmt::{self, Display};

struct Point {
    pub x: u8,
    pub y: u8,
}

impl Display for Point {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({}, {})", self.x, self.y)
    }
}

struct Line {
    pub start: Point,
    pub end: Point,
}

impl Display for Line {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({}, {})", self.start, self.end)
    }
}

struct Data {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
    index: usize,
}

impl Data {
    fn new(vec: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        Self { vec, index: 0 }
    }

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&dyn Display> {
        let obj;

        self.index += 1;

        match self.vec[self.index] {
            0 => {
                obj = Some(/* &Point { ... } with address equal to &(self.vec[self.index])*/);
                self.index += std::mem::size_of::<Point>();
            }

            1 => {
                obj = Some(/* &Line { ... } with address equal to &(self.vec[self.index])*/);
                self.index += std::mem::size_of::<Line>();
            }

            _ => {
                obj = None;
            }
        }

        obj
    }
}

fn main() {
    let raw_vec: Vec<u8> = vec![0, 24, 53, 1, 65, 103, 68, 10, 2];
    let data = Data::new(raw_vec);
    assert!(format!("{}", data.next().unwrap()) == "(24, 53)".to_string());
    assert!(format!("{}", data.next().unwrap()) == "((65, 103), (68, 10))".to_string());
}
```

Multiple `struct`s of different length will share their data with the `Vec<u8>`. In this example, the memory layout of my `struct`s may not match what I suppose they are, but this does not matter because their layout does not need to be known at compile time, but only at runtime. think of the `Vec<u8>` as the bytes read from a file by the program while the file itself was created by this same program.

How would I do that, even if it's unsafe or undefined behavior and without using smart pointers/heap allocation?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to wrap a borrowed value in a newtype that is also a borrowed value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53999600/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=738421a39204e5c5d8cb115e2347fed2)

Comment: _"How would I do that, even if it's unsafe or undefined behavior?"_ -- you mean, how can you make this sometimes work, sometimes segfault, sometimes just give random data and sometimes cause unexpected bugs in unrelated parts of your program?

Comment: *can also suppose I know for certain the data layout of `Point`* — you do not, based on this code. `repr(Rust)` has no guarantees about layout.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your *modified* situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=37d6d5885b8f4cbb6bde870acf5293b5)

Comment: Your latest update doesn't attempt to explain why the marked duplicates (along with the duplicates applied to your situation) are not correct.

Comment: See also [Transmuting u8 buffer to struct in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42499049/155423); [Can I take a byte array and deserialize it into a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36061560/155423); [How to read a struct from a file in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25410028/155423)