# How can PathBuf::deref() return a reference to a temporary?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I stumbled on [this standard library code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.51.0/library/std/src/path.rs#L1539-L1546):

```rust
impl ops::Deref for PathBuf {
    type Target = Path;
    #[inline]
    fn deref(&self) -> &Path {
        Path::new(&self.inner)
    }
}
```

How can this work? This seems to be creating a temporary on the stack and then returns a reference to it. Isn't that an obvious lifetime violation?

Comment: *then returns a reference to it* — what is the temporary, and where is a reference to it taken? Recall that references are created with the `&` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Path::new` [uses `unsafe` code to convert an `&OsStr` to a `&Path`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.51.0/library/std/src/path.rs#L1777-L1779):

```rust
pub fn new<S: AsRef<OsStr> + ?Sized>(s: &S) -> &Path {
    unsafe { &*(s.as_ref() as *const OsStr as *const Path) }
}
```

If you read [the internal documentation for `Path`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.51.0/library/std/src/path.rs#L1724-L1731):

```
// `Path::new` current implementation relies
// on `Path` being layout-compatible with `OsStr`.
// When attribute privacy is implemented, `Path` should be annotated as `#[repr(transparent)]`.
// Anyway, `Path` representation and layout are considered implementation detail, are
// not documented and must not be relied upon.
pub struct Path {
    inner: OsStr,
}
```

See also:

- [How to wrap a borrowed value in a newtype that is also a borrowed value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53999600/155423)